# Checking for existing path / filename is taking too long in VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm creating an application that has a TextBox which attempts to update a PictureBox when the user enters a filename.

It has a preset directory which all users will use, which is on a Shared network folder. It also checks if the user is inputting an entire path and filename, it will display the image accordingly.

The code works, however, if the user starts typing in "C:\Filename...", the code will hang for several seconds after the "C:". The bigger issue I have is that if the user disconnects from the network drive, the app will keep looking for it for 10 or 20 seconds, which isn't necessary, I'd rather it stop trying if it doesn't see it for 2 seconds.

```
Dim myCallback As New Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(AddressOf ThumbnailCallback)

'If the user's entry exists as a filename, display it in the picturebox
If Dir(txtGrab.Text) <> "" Then
   Dim myBitmap As New Bitmap(txtGrab.Text)
   Dim myThumbnail As Image = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero)
   myThumbnail.GetThumbnailImage(BorderSize, BorderSize, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero)
   imgDisplay.Image = myThumbnail
End If

'If the user's entry exists within intranet's path, display in picturebox
If Dir("\\Intranet\Images\" & txtGrab.Text & ".tif") <> "" Then
     Dim myBitmap As New Bitmap("\\Intranet\" & txtGrab.Text & ".tif")
     Dim myThumbnail As Image = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero)
     myThumbnail.GetThumbnailImage(BorderSize, BorderSize, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero)
     frmCodeGrabber.imgDisplay.Image = myThumbnail
End If
```

Comment: oh...so long content...will you please elaborate in short?

Comment: so this method is execute every time user types in the textbox (i.e., the textchanged event)?

Comment: You should call this from your `Validating` event, not your `TextChanged`, `Keyup` or `Keypress` events.